# Can't display downloaded image from RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fs

I've successfully saved the image from url with the response 
{"jobId" : 1, "statucCode" : 200, "byteWritten" : 127744 }

but I can't display the image.

downloadFile(){

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

const uri = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525184275980-9028ceb8e09f?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80' ; 
const name = shorthash.unique(uri);
const path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${name}.png`;

RNFS.downloadFile({fromUrl:uri, toFile: path}).promise
    .then((res) => { 
        this.setState({ source:{uri:path}}) ;
    }).catch((err) => { 
        alert(err)
     });
}
```

the state will be like source : { "uri" : "path" }

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: @Tim I've updated the the questions with a download file function that I've created then set the path to the state source

Comment: How do you want to display the image?

Comment: <Image source={this.state.source}/>

Comment: Do you specify a height and width for the image?

Comment: omg I didn't put the width and height, and I just tried it  it works!! thank you!!

Comment: I would transform my comment into an answer. I would appreciate an upvote and marking it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems right, but you are probably missing to sepcify a width and a height for your image.

For example:

```
<Image source={this.state.source} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
```